# Unable to get Login after creating custom login page in Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a simple login project through the database using Spring Boot and I am simply able to complete my project through this code.

> HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

> AppSecurityConfig.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService  userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

> MyUserDetailsService.java

```
    @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repo;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = repo.findByUsername(username);
            if(user==null)
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User 404");
            return new UserPrinciple(user);
        }
   }
```

> User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

> UserPrinciple.java

```
public class UserPrinciple implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public UserPrinciple(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Here I am getting successfully logged in but, my problem is when I tried to create my own custom page and get login through the database and I created two JSP and creating some changes into my `AppSecurityConfig.java` and `HomeController.java`:

> login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
        <form action="Login"method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td> <input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td> <input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

> logout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        Logout home<br>
        <a href="/">home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/logout-success")
    public String logoutPage() {
        return "logout.jsp";
    }
}
```

> AppSecurityConfig.java

```
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService  userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();

    }
}
```

After this, I successfully get my custom page but when I tried to get login with the username and password stored into the database at the moment I hit the submit button my entries were gone and nothing happens, even I got nothing into my console to figure out my problem.

Even when i tried with wrong username and password the spring boot security not even shows any message of bad credentials or nothing , so tell me where I am creating mistakes and how to solve it.

Comment: Your auth provider doesn't do a thing. Instead implement a method to configure the `AuthenticationMnaager` to use your own `userDetailsService`.

Comment: @M.Deinum sir I noticed a thing that even I add  spring boot security dependency to my pom.xml   still I am not getting the default login page provided by spring security what all I get is a customized security page

Comment: Ofcourse you get the customized one, as that is what you configured it to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum sir how can implement a method to configure Authentication Manager to use userDetailsService

Comment: Could you add which Spring Boot version you are using? With a recent version a new version of Spring Security should be included (unless you override it!). Which should detect the `UserDetailsService` automatically. You shouldn't need an `AuthenticationProvider` at all. Else add a method that takes an `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as argument, add `@Autowired` on it, and use that to add the `userDetailsService` to the `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Spring boot version 2.2.2

Comment: In your form  you are posting to `Login` which should be `/login` (URLs are case-sensitive).

Comment: @M.Deinum Request passed to dispatcher already passed HttpFirewall and normalized, so case is actually ignored.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right sir form must posting to /login.  Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @M.Deinum sir I want to add a point that I am getting the customized login page from spring boot security even before I adding the code for my custom login page in login.jsp

Comment: Showing the form is something completely different then processing the form.